# Link between openssl 'req' command and 'unable to get local issuer certificate'?

Tags: openssl, certificates

I was using the following command to build a self-signed certificate after creating a private key:

`openssl x509 -in "server.csr" -out "server.crt" -req -signkey "myprivate.key" -days 365`

After some ensuing troubles, and lots of googling I cobbled together a script, which culminated in:

`openssl req -config ${CONFIGFILE} -new -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout "server.key" -days 365 -out "server.crt"`

**How does this work, *given I'm no longer passing it my "myprivate.key" to actually self-sign the cert?***

Is "server.key" now being used to do the signing, and do I need to somehow combine this new key with the original "myprivate.key" to create a keychain? I ask since commandline tools don't seem to like the resulting certificate (e.g. curl says: 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second command *generates* a new RSA key and writes it in `server.key`, along with the self-signed certificate in `server.crt`.

Comment: Hi @conrado, I'm going to accept your answer since server.key is indeed a net new key. With regard to the part of my question about 'Do i need to somehow combine....' ... I learned later that what I needed was a separate self-signed key, acting as a CA, to sign this server request. Hope it helps someone else.